# Can a person “sincerely” disbelieve? If so, what’s their fate?

Tags: jannah, forgiveness, kufr, jahannam

I’m not too familiar with the ins and outs of Islam, so forgive my ignorance.
I was wondering, after Islam was revealed, whether a non-muslim could be admitted to paradise if he “sincerely” disbelieves in the religion; meaning that said person was honest about his assessment of the Message and found it unconvincing, for any number of reasons, which seem legitimate to the one who holds them.

What would be his likely fate?

And has this subject matter been addressed at all by the scholars?

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/64039/